# Looking for a voice recording software with visualizer

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking for a software that will let me record my voice and create a video with visualizer (correct me if my choice of words is wrong) that is sensitive to my voice like TV professionals show on screen when they do not have a video footage to go with it. A wave that moves up and down when the person is speaking and comes to rest when there's no audio activity.

Here's an example of what I want as the end product (see how it's jumps only when the music is playing):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xBYjZV74iYE

but a lot more formal and preferably in a wave format ().

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to use Quick Time Player to record your voice? note that the visual could you wnat is up to you and it could be done by VLC player.

Comment: I would prefer if I do not have to capture my screen and the video is saved.

Comment: it will only record your voice then, you have two separate options, either record your voice / capture your screen.